# What program can blur a photo to show motion?

Tags: software, post-processing, blur, image-manipulation, motion-blur

I have a picture in the woods of a path. I want to blur the woods so they look like they are being run by really fast, not just plain blurry. The best analogy I can think of is like cars look on highways in certain pictures.

What program can do this?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Do you want to do this on your computer? What type of computer do you have, windows or mac? Do you have any software already that you want to try to do this in, such as Photoshop Elements, Gimp, or similar?

Answer (score 7):

In Photoshop, you can access various blurs via the Blur sub-menu in Filters menu.

- Motion Blur will ask for an angle and an intensity and will blur the entire image (or selection) along that angle making it look like the camera exposed for motion.
- Radial blur will ask for a point and an intensity and will blur the pixels radially away from that point as if the camera has zoomed in over the course of the exposure.
- Zoom blur will ask for a point and an intensity and will blur the pixels in a circular *around* that point as if the camera was spun on it's axis during the exposure.

Comment: Edited for clarity and added explanations.

Answer (score 2):

Gimp has a filter called [Motion blur](http://docs.gimp.org/en/plug-in-mblur.html) - try it. Here is also some [videotutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EN3zqyF1sOI), how to do it.